# Does this launch circuit look correct?

Tags: power, led, layout

I'm trying to design a circuit which will pass through an electric match to light it on fire from a safe distance, with indicators.

I know it could be done simply and as is, but this is for fun, not just pure function.

I'm trying to have an LED and piezo buzzer light up and sound when the safety switch is closed, and another LED light up as when the fire switch is closed.

The electric match is a charge which I am making that lights on fire when enough current passes through it (a few amps at least). (Match with thin wire and a lot of current -- replaced after every activation.)

Does this look correct? Also, how would I make the second LED work without anything interfering?

[image]

Comment: your circuit is 1/2 correct ... how would you connect a buzzer and led so that no current passes through the match when the buzzer is activated?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by: "will pass through a match to light it on fire". Could you elaborate on it?

Comment: A specification that would help a lot, if you can get it, is called the "all-fire" spec. For example, an Estes ignitor has an all-fire specification of \$\frac12 \:\text{Joule}\$ delivered in \$50\:\text{ms}\$ into a load of \$\frac23\:\Omega\$. That tells you ***everything*** you need about their ignitors in order to make a proper design.

Comment: (The Estes all-fire specification implies an average of \$\sqrt{\frac{\left[\frac{\frac12\:\text{J}}{50\:\text{ms}}\right]}{\frac23\:\Omega}}\approx 3.9\:\text{A}\$.)

Comment: Rodo,  my intention is to pass a large amount of current through a very small section of wire wrapped around a match head, hopefully setting it on fire.  It needs a fair amount of current, and will not light if only a small amount goes through the wire

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvEABQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That should work. When the first switch is closed, the first LED D1 will light and the buzzer will operate. When the second switch is closed, the second LED D2 will light when the match burns open.